# R data.table: efficient ways to add days (01) to a date

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(n = c("A", "B"), dt_start = c("10/2020", "05/2015"))
```

I want:

```
DT <- data.table(n = c("A", "B"), dt_start = c("2020-10-01", "2015-05-01"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste0` to add the day to the character and use `as.Date` to coerce it:

```r
DT[, dt_start := as.Date(paste0("01/", DT$dt_start), "%d/%m/%Y")]
```

The result is

```r
DT
   n   dt_start
1: A 2020-10-01
2: B 2015-05-01
```

Comment: How to do with the format : data.table(n = c("A", "B"), dt_start = c("may-20", "janv-20"))

Comment: You can try `%b` instead of `%m` which corresponds to the abbreviated month name. You can also check the documentation with `?strptime` to get a list of options